# How do i use both BorderLayout and SpringLayout together?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jpanel

I'm very new at this. I wanted to use border layout to place panels and for spring layout to place the labels, buttons and all that. Right now i have it like this for the spring: I left out extras to save reading.

```
            frame = new JFrame();
    contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
    contentPane.setLayout(layout);
            contentPane.add(mybutton);
    contentPane.add(currentState);
```

it works fine without the borderLayout, but as soon as i put the below right under it, it replaces my spring layout(the buttons, labels) instead. What am i doing wrong?

```
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(navPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Comment: Never set layout or add component to the frame, you only have to work with the contentPane, maybe specify better what you want to do

Comment: you are right, i was watching a video and the guy was primarily working with the contentPane!

Answer (score 1):

Here, your `ContentPane` is nested inside your `JFrame Layout`.

In your code, you add some components to the `ContentPane` and after that, you override the `JFrame Layout` which 'erases' the `Content Pane`

What you might want to do is to set your layout for the `JFrame` for `BorderLayout`, then create a `JPanel` and add your elements inside. Following that, add your `JPanel` in your frame, and not the other way around.

Comment: ah, i'm onto something else at the moment but i find your reply very interesting and helpful later. I'll get back to you, thanks for your insight, i need more rep to upvote you

Answer (score 0):

you can put one layout on their own Jpanel, I used this before.